# Flag duplicate obs between based on two ID variables

Tags: r, data.table

**Updated Example (see RULES)**

I have data.table with id1 and id2 columns (as below)

```
data.table(id1=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4), id2=c(1,2,2,1,2,3,2))
```

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |

I would like to generate a flag to identify the duplicate association between id1 and id2.

**RULE** : if a particular id1 is already associated with id2 then it should be flagged..one unique id2 should be associated with one id1 only (see explanation below)

**a) Looking for an efficient solution and b) a solution that only uses basics and data.table functions**

| id1 | id2 | flag |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | Y | <== since id2=1is assicated with id1=1 in 1st row |
| 2 | 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | Y | <== since id2=1 is assicated with id1=1 in 1st row |
| 3 | 2 | Y | <== since id2=2 is assicated with id1=2 in 3rd row |
| 3 | 3 |  |  |
| 4 | 2 | Y | <== since id2=2 is assicated with id1=2 in 3rd row |

Comment: The example data you created `data.table(id1=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4), id2=c(1,2,2,1,2,3,2))` and the one showed is different

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Maybe you are looking for an `igraph` relationship

Comment: yes. is there easy way to using data.table

Comment: igraph may be more efficient

Comment: isn't it possible to go backward relatively using shift() and then if id2 is already associated within the same id1 group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236827/discussion-between-r007-and-akrun).

Comment: What is the basis to flag the pair c(1, 2) instead of c(2, 2) (id1, id2)?

Comment: each id1 will be associated with id2 once and each id2 will be associated with id1 only

Comment: What is the expected result if an `id1` group has only `id2` values which already have been consumed in previous rows? Are then all rows of this group flagged? E.g., `data.table(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), id2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. If I understand correctly, my translation of OP's rules is as follows:

1. For each `id1` group, exactly one row is *not* flagged.
2. If the `id1` group consists only of one row it is *not* flagged.
3. Within an `id1` group, all rows where `id2` has been used in previous groups are flagged.
4. If there are more than one row within an `id1` group which have not been flagged up to now, only the first row is *not* flagged; all other rows are flagged.

So, the approach is to

- create a vector of available `id2` values,
- step through the `id1` groups,

  - find the first row within each group where the `id2` value not already has been consumed in previous groups,
  - flag all other rows,
  - and update the vector of available (not consumed) `id2` values.

```
avail <- unique(DT$id2)
DT[, flag := {
  idx <- max(first(which(id2 %in% avail)), 1L)
  avail <- setdiff(avail, id2)
  replace(rep("Y", .N), idx, "")
}, by = id1][]
```

> ```
>    id1 id2 flag
> 1:   1   1     
> 2:   1   2    Y
> 3:   2   2     
> 4:   3   1    Y
> 5:   3   2    Y
> 6:   3   3     
> 7:   4   2
> ```

#### Caveat

The above code reproduces the expected result for the use case provided by the OP. However, there might be other uses cases and/or edge cases where the code might need to be tweaked to comply with OP's expectations. E.g., it is unclear what the expected result is in case of an `id1` group where *all* `id2` values already have been consumed in previous groups.

#### Edit:

The OP has edited the expected result so that row 7 is now flagged as well.

Here is a tweaked version of my code which reproduces the expected result after the edit:

```
avail <- unique(DT$id2)
DT[, flag := {
  idx <- first(which(id2 %in% avail))
  avail <- setdiff(avail, id2[idx])
  replace(rep("Y", .N), idx, "")
}, by = id1][]
```

> ```
>    id1 id2 flag
> 1:   1   1     
> 2:   1   2    Y
> 3:   2   2     
> 4:   3   1    Y
> 5:   3   2    Y
> 6:   3   3     
> 7:   4   2    Y
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4),
                id2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really convoluted chain, but I think it produces the result (the result in your question does not follow your own logic):

```
library(data.table)
a = data.table(id1=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4), id2=c(1,2,2,1,2,3,2))

a[, .SD[1, ], by = id2][, 
                       Noflag := "no"][a, 
                                       on = .(id2, id1)][is.na(Noflag), 
                                                         flag := "y"][,
                                                                      Noflag := NULL][]
```

What's in there:

- `a[, .SD[1, ], by = id2]` gets each first row of the subgroups by `id2`. This groups **shouldn't be flagged**, so
- `[, Noflag := "no"]` flags them as "not flagged" (go figure. I said it was convoluted). We need to join this no-flagged table with the original one:
- `[a, on = .(id2, id1)]` joins the last table with the original `a` on both `id1` and `id2`. Now we need to flag the rows that aren't flagged as "shouldn't be flagged":
- `[is.na(Noflag), flag := "y"]`. Last part is to remove the `Noflag` unnecessary column:
- `[, Noflag := NULL]` and add a `[]` to display the new table to screen.

I agree with the comment by @akrun reagarding `igraph` being not only more efficient, but also a simpler sintax.

Comment: thanks, I am exploring igraph as well. (fyi, output which I have put out there originally is exactly what is expected but then I realized that rule which I explained was not correct so I edited to avoid confusion for other users)

Comment: Unfortunately, running your code I was not able to reproduce OP's expected result for some reason. E.g., with your code, row 2 is not flagged (which should be), while row 3 is flagged (which shouldn't). I'm not sure if this is due to a mistake on my side in copying your code. Perhaps, it would be helpful if you could edit you answer and show also your result. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe, great answer from you. I just get lost in the many edits around the time I answered (see edits 2 to 5 of the question, not only in the expected results table, but also on the explantation of rules). To be honest, I came to fully understand the rules _by reading your answer_.

Answer (score 0):

```
# replicate your data
df <- data.table(id1=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4), id2=c(1,2,2,1,2,3,2))


# create and append a new, empty column that will late be filled with the info whether they match or not
empty_col <- rep(NA, nrow(df)) #create empty vector
df[ , `:=` (duplicate = empty_col)] #append to existing data set

# create loop, to iteratively check if statement is true, then fill the new column accordingly  
# note that instead of indexing the columns (e.g. df[,3] you could also use their names (e.g. df$flag)  


for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (i>=2 & df[i,1] == df[1:i-1,1]){ #check if value in loop I matches that of any rows before (1:i)
    df[i,3] = 1 
  }
  else {
    df[i,3] = 0 # when they dont match: 0, false
  }
}

# note that the loop only starts in the second row, as i-1 would be 0 for i=1, such that there would be an error.
```

Comment: I would prefer data.table instead of for-loop since it is not efficient. fyi, I updated the example to make it little more cleaner.

Comment: If that's the case, your question still isn't super clear on that. Maybe editing it to say that you're looking for 'a)  an efficient solution and b) a solution that only uses basics and data.table functions' would be more clear. Maybe if you detailed on what you thought of when you say "I can think of logic in multiple steps but wondering if there is an easy way to accomplish this" would help

Comment: Thanks, I updated as you suggested. fyi, I thought I could solve this problem by doing iterations but none of the options is efficient.